# Exclude IPs from a range to avoid conflict

Tags: linux, bash, ip, ipv4

I have a long list of IPs and ranges, and I want to debug my list, deleting IPs that generate conflict with *CIDR*.

For example:

```
8.8.8.0/24
8.8.8.8
23.236.62.147
23.236.48.0/20
104.154.76.93
104.154.0.0/15
etc
```

So I need to delete `23.236.62.147` (because it is a subnetwork of `23.236.48.0/20`), `104.154.76.93` (because it is a subnetwork of `104.154.0.0/15`), `8.8.8.8` (because is a subnetwork of `8.8.8.0/24`), etc, etc

How to do it in bash/command linux?

Comment: So what you actually want to do is remove *redundant* entries.

Comment: entries (ips) in conflict with CIDR ranges

Comment: Do you have access to Python, or does this have to be done only in Bash?

Comment: Preferably in bash, but if python works....

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash and GNU grep:

```
#!/bin/bash

common() {
  # From http://stackoverflow.com/a/35114656/3776858

  D2B=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
  declare -i c=0                              # set integer attribute

  # read and convert IPs to binary
  IFS=./ read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 m <<< "$1"
  b1="${D2B[$a1]}${D2B[$a2]}${D2B[$a3]}${D2B[$a4]}"

  IFS=./ read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 m <<< "$2"
  b2="${D2B[$a1]}${D2B[$a2]}${D2B[$a3]}${D2B[$a4]}"

  # find number of same bits ($c) in both IPs from left, use $c as counter
  for ((i=0;i<32;i++)); do
    [[ ${b1:$i:1} == ${b2:$i:1} ]] && c=c+1 || break
  done    

  # create string with zeros
  for ((i=$c;i<32;i++)); do
    fill="${fill}0"
  done    

  # append string with zeros to string with identical bits to fill 32 bit again
  new="${b1:0:$c}${fill}"

  # convert binary $new to decimal IP with netmask
  new="$((2#${new:0:8})).$((2#${new:8:8})).$((2#${new:16:8})).$((2#${new:24:8}))/$c"
  echo "$new"
}


cidr="$1"

# using process substitution
grep -vxFf <(
  grep -v / "$cidr" | while IFS= read -r ip1; do
    grep / "$cidr" | while IFS=/ read -r ip2 mask2; do
      out=$(common "$ip2/$mask2" "$ip1/32")
      out_mask="${out#*/}"
      if [[ $out_mask -ge $mask2 ]]; then   # -ge: greater-than-or-equal
        echo "$ip1"
      fi
    done
  done
) "$cidr" > cidr_clean.txt
```

Usage: `./shadow.sh your_cidr_file.txt`

In your current directory you will get cidr_clean.txt:

```
8.8.8.0/24
23.236.48.0/20
104.154.0.0/15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would greatly appreciate that you modify your script to run only ./shadow.sh (not ./shadow.sh your_cidr_file.txt. Put inside the script your_cidr_file.txt). Thanks

Comment: Do you want to replace `cidr="$1"` by `cidr="your_cidr_file.txt"`? If that is not your intention, I recommend you to start a new question with this new specification.

Comment: What do you think if I make this modification to your script?: grep -vxFf shadow.txt "$cidr" | sort -u | sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n > cidr_clean.txt

Comment: That's no problem. I've removed output of file shadow.txt.

Comment: I have a problem with your script. It takes many hours (possibly days with a list of 3m of ips) even if the list does not contain CIDR or has one or two CIDRs. Could you add some CIDR detection mechanism to make it faster?. Thanks

Comment: Bash is a slow script language. If you prefer performace I suggest to start a new question to get an implementation in Perl, Python or C.

Comment: I suggest to use Perl, Python or C. Sorry, I can not help you there.